# I have multiplatform apps in node-webkit. How do I convert them to nw.js?

Tags: node-webkit, nwjs

I have a bunch of applications that run fine using node-webkit on Macs and Windows.
(They mostly live on shared Dropbox folders.  They read and write to data files in the folder).

I gather node-webkit will not run on Mac Catalina.
So I am trying to figure out how to install and use nw.js

I need the Mac and Win versions of the app to be in the same directory. Multiple users will run their local Dropbox version of the app, and read/write to the shared data folders.

I cannot figure out how to get convert the app from node-webkit to nw.js
I've been unable to find an "idiot's guide" to this.

Any suggestions, or pointers to resources, would be most helpful.

Thanks in advance.
And apologies for posting what is probably a dumb question for most users of this site....

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your app's old source code (node-webkit) with NW.js and fix all the exceptions thrown. You can find the migration guide [here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/).

Comment: Only area that I cannot figure out: Writing to persisting file in Mac.  In Node-webkit, I wrote to file in same folder where package.json lived.  Now, all the files are in a Mac package, and it tries to write not to the same folder, but to a read-only folder with path starting   private/var/.....  Can't find a reference for "how to write to file relative to location of the executable..."